# Problems displaying yLabels in charts.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linechart

I am pretty new to charts.js and I am trying to make a custom line chart with custom y-Labels.

Unfortunately I can't get my yLabels to stick.

I am adding them to an array in a loop like this:

```
yLabelsList.push(yLabel);
```

After the loop I just do this:

```
lineChartData.yLabels = yLabelsList;
ctx1 = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
myLineChart = new Chart(ctx1, {type: 'line', data: lineChartData,});
```

My data get's added in big arrays, using either null or the corresponding y label value.

Unfortunately my chart stays blank without an error.

Comment: post working example ..

Answer (score 0):

`ylabels` is not a valid property. Use [`labels`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html#tick-configuration-options) instead:

```
lineChartData.labels = yLabelsList;
```

Comment: @Barbarian772 Did this answer your question?

Comment: It pushed me to the right track at least. .labels itself just sets the x-axis labels. To set the labels for the yAxes the easiest thing I found was setting the yAxes.labels option in scales in the chart options.